# in plane deformation using image sequence (conceptual )

Tags: image-processing

:
I have a sequence of images of a plane object with some targets on it. Some of these targets are stable, but some of them are moving. 
Limitation:
My stable points don't form rectangle required for projective transformation.

Question: How can I find the in plane deformation using image sequenc of instable points.

Comment: Have you considered affine transformations? These can be computed from optical flow. For example, in Python or Matlab, there are several existing techniques for tracking based on optical flow. These usually compute the intermediary affine transformations required to move a small image patch (i.e. a rectangle around your instable points) from one frame to the next frame. There are methods for stitching several of these transformations together to get a best-estimate of the global affine transformation. I did this once for identifying the license plate of a fast-moving car.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to have a look at [**thin-plate splines**](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/tpsdemo/).

The "2D point morph example" is probably what you want (if I understand correctly your statement).